# How to create symbolic links for custom installation without root permission?

Tags: installation, cmake, root, symlink

First of all, I must say I'm not very comfortable with UNIX commands, shell language etc.
I'm willing to install Google library SentencePiece (> https://github.com/google/sentencepiece), which is a dependency of a fairseq script to preprocess some speech data. I followed installation procedure as stated in the README.md from the git repo.

I do not have root privileges, hence I couldn't install it the precognized way with cmake (meaning in /etc), and I had to install it in a custom directory.
For the same reasons, as I do not have root privileges nor access to /etc directory, I couldn't execute the last line : `sudo ldconfig -v`. Trying the execution without sudo obviously returned a permission error.
And now, if I try to call a function from SentencePiece, I get an error :

```
spm_train: error while loading shared libraries: libsentencepiece_train.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I understand it comes from the fact that I did not build any link between thoses dependencies (and the executable file ?) as I couldn't execute `ldconfig`, hence I do not know if I should call it with a specified path pointing to my customized directory (hence not needing root privileges as not needing access to /etc ?) or if I need to use another command ? In both cases, I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `ldconfig -n path/to/shared/libs`

and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/shared/libs` seems to solve my problem !